# Need to create an api doc for an existing application written with nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, api-doc, iodocs

I have a few private apis written in plain old express.  Time to let it out and provide some api documentation.

What I don't want (at least yet) it to re-write my express app to integrate api documentation into the code.  Mainly since I am not sure what framework or spec to use to document my api I don't really want to be locking into one particular thing.

I would like to serve out the doc as part of a sub resource under my api (ie I do not want to run a different server or subdomain).  Maybe '/api/docs'.  A plus would also be a UI that I could embed within my app that could parse the docs and at the very least provide a nice presentation of the docs in html (api interaction is a plus).

Things like [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) are cool, but would require me to re-write all my express code to integrate swagger.  At that point I have a big investment and am tightly coupled to swagger.

Is there a way to serve out swagger or iodocs or maybe something else to document my api in a way that is minimally invasive to existing routes?

EDIT:

I could serve out the Swagger spec from a hand written doc.  Problem I see is that you have to define `basePath` in the swagger doc.  This does not really allow me to easily deploy under different domains.

Comment: You could always fire up notepad and manually write your documentation as an .html file :)  Here are two lists that include many alternatives, such as [Mashery](http://www.mashery.com/product/io-docs): http://www.infoq.com/research/api-documentation

Comment: you should know that there is a swagger ui too which will parse your specs and show it beautifully + api integration provided you write the specs according to swagger specification.

Comment: Thanks, I did see that there is a swagger-ui.  Do you know if I can just add that as a dependency to an existing node project?

Comment: swagger-ui is a set of static html files with js and css. There are also npm packages of it - https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui.

Answer (score 7):

There's a wide array of node.js tools to integrate Swagger with your application, and I assume they offer different ways of doing so. You can find a list of such integrations here - https://github.com/webron/swagger-spec/#nodejs - but I can tell you that there are additional tools out there that are not listed there. You can try searching github for swagger and node/express.

As for the manual spec and the basePath - Swagger 2.0 actually solves that for you. You can use the online editor - http://editor.swagger.io - to write your specs in a more human-friendly YAML form, which then you can export to JSON. 
Unlike Swagger 1.2 and previous versions, the basePath is now split into three properties - `schemes` (http, https), `host` (domain, port) and `basePath` (the root context of the application). None of these properties are mandatory, and they all default to whatever is serving the swagger.json file (the spec itself). `schemes` defaults to the scheme service the swagger.json, `host` defaults to the host used for serving the swagger.json and `basePath` will be `\` unless explicitly specified. I believe this should solve your concerns regarding the basePath.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  Do you know if you can spilt your swagger files into parts?  I.E. one file for each resource and have the parts combined before serving out?

Comment: In 2.0 you theoretically can, but there's an issue we need to resolve there so I wouldn't use that option just yet. For now, it's better to keep it all in a single file, though there are ways to ease up model, parameter and response repetitions.

Comment: I used http://editor.swagger.io . What should I do after writing YAML doc and then download the json swagger file ?

I need to integrate it to my nodejs app.

Comment: @MostafaKhattab that depends on how you integrate it. If it's documenting an existing API, the way to combine the two would be using components that support a design-first approach like swagger-node. Otherwise, you'll need to host is independently without special integration.